# ListView add View at the desired position in the list

Tags: android, listview

Is there a method similar to ListView#AddHeader or ListView#AddFooter which will add view after desired position in the list?

Answer (score 1):

May be check out this project on github: [StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add your row to your data set in desired position and then call notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I don't want to add another object in the data set. I want to have custom layout between two positions in the list.

Comment: I can't understand your problem! but you can add your view to your desired item!
Do you want to have custom divider or something like this?

Comment: Yes, custom divider would be the best choice of words. Let's say, I have list of 5 items. I want to have custom divider between third and fourth item. Size of data set should still be 5, not 6.

Comment: if custom divider position is static , you can add custom divider as a view in your getView method when its inflating view for third item! am I clear?

Comment: It would still be part of view of third item. And it would react on click. I dont want that.

Comment: you can set clickListener to your custom divider if your problem is just react to on click!

Comment: I'm also using drag-sort listview. And it wouldnt work well with that. I want that divider view to be separated from items views.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to add OTHER controls in the view? After and Before the ListView???

Just wrap the ListView in a LinearLayout (orientation=vertical) and insert the views that you want...

I hope it helps you!

Comment: I want to add linear layout which contains textview between two positions in the listview. I don't want it to be a part of data set.

Comment: addHeader(view) adds custom view to the top of listview. I want to add it somewhere in the middle.

Comment: do you mean "add in every listview item"? if so, define the listview item with an xml file, have you tried that?

Comment: not every. I want to add one custom view between only two items which I will specify. I don't want it to be a part of the view of any item.

Comment: I think you should explain the logic of what you want, because it's hard to understand why the typical solutions don't fix the problem... give us an example, please